# How to remap keys after Alt+Tab/Ctrl+Tab while Alt/Ctrl is currently being held?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I am trying to use VIM a lot in my day to day life, and I prefer not to move my hands away from the home row. That being said I do alt tab/ctrl tab a lot, but its tedious to keep pressing TAB to cycle applications. When you press Alt+tab and keep alt pressed down, i would like to remap hjkl to the arrow keys only when ALT is currently held down AFTER pressing ALT+Tab. Is it possible to do this in AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 2):

when you press Alt+Tab you enter a new framework called the `MultitaskingViewFrame`

so you need to work from within this context.

try this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MultitaskingViewFrame
i::up
j::left
k::down
l::right
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I'd suggest doing some research about hotkeys within hotkeys and come back with a script we can help you tweak.

Comment: Looking at the hotkeys within hotkeys im having trouble finding anything. I have already done hotkeys, such as mapping Capslock to Escape, and Ctrl+Win+Left to Ctrl+Win+J.

Any other pointers/information you could give me?

Comment: I'm not at all confident that something that complex _**is**_ possible in AutoHotkey, based on running into brick walls with things I've tried to do.